# Where can i find a document explaining how Objective-C is implemented

Tags: objective-c

I mean the fundamental runtime. How is method dispatching implemented (via a selector hashtable?). What is a selector anyway? How is the object model as you can add methods later with some low level API  etc.

I need to look at it from a compiler programming point of view, not a simple user of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a few docs to get you started (should help you google the right questions):

- http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/artikel/Optimization/opti-9.html
- http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html

Comment: Thanks the first text is almost what i wanted.
I had read the second already but it does not say anything about the implementation. Now the only part left is the parameter passing and checking algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

Use the source.

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437/

And for parsing, look to Clang:

http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html